# mysql - import only schema from full dump?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have a full database export (single file, schama + data), but I would like to import only the database schema. Is there any magic option or trick to achieve this?
I'm NOT able to perform a "mysql_dump --no-data" at the original database at this moment. Is removing all inserts and updates manual (awk/grep/vim) from the dump file the only option?

Comment: Edit the dump file and copy out only the schema part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mysqldump is only inserts, not updates. So `grep -v "^INSERT" dump.sql` should be sufficient. Take a look before using

Comment: I was expecing a magic option for mysql import, but finaly, I have filtered out the inserts. Even if the dump file was 2+GB, it went quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, do

```
mysqldump --no-data ...
```

to get just the schema.